# What `<` is for in bash

Tags: bash

So I'm taking a course at a university and the professor tells us to run our program like this `java -cp classes cst420.Waypoint < samples.txt`. What exactly is the `<` doing in this command? I know it's taking the samples.txt as input but I'm curious on exactly what's going on here.

Comment: That's running the program, not compiling it.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that correction, I meant run.

Comment: It's using samples.txt as an input stream, instead of you typing the same contents from console.

Comment: It grabs input from the standard input, which becomes samples.txt, on most systems. If you're on unix, you can also do `cat samples.txt | "java -cp classes cst420.Waypoint -` to achieve the same effect

Comment: see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html for more info on I/O redirections

Comment: @Thomas, the ABS has a tendency to showcase bad practices in its examples, so while it's rarely inaccurate, it also isn't always a good reference to recommend to folks who can't filter the wheat from the chaff. I'd suggest http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055 instead.

Comment: @hd1, a similar effect, yes. The same effect, not quite -- the redirection provides a seekable file handle; the pipeline from a `cat` process provides a stream.

Answer (score 0):

It grabs input from the standard input, which becomes samples.txt, on most systems. If you're on unix, you can also do cat samples.txt | "java -cp classes cst420.Waypoint - to achieve a similar effect.

The difference being you can't seek on piped input and can on feeding it into the JVM (h/t @CharlesDuffy).